# Posting a text to Facebook from a selected table cell

Tags: iphone

I have a table view with bible verses on each cell. I want to post the verse to Facebook.

I have already done the posting with static text from a textview.

When I tap the cell, an action sheet pops up and there is a button to go to the posting page. This works, the posting page has a textview. How do I get the text view in the posting page to display the content of the selected cell from the tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the selected verse in an instance variable (of type `NSString*`).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     self.verseToBePosted = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath].label.text; //whatever is holding the verse

     //other stuff

}
```

Then, in the action sheet delegate, use this instance variable for posting-

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      //post if the post button was pressed
      [self postToFB:self.verseToBePosted]; //whatever your function name is
}
```

Comment: here is the problem ,the action sheet button is used to navigate to posting page ,there is a textview in the posting page ,the verse have to be posted from there.

Comment: If the two are in different classes, then you could either save the verse in a model class or pass it via an `NSNotification`.

Comment: [DbHandler createBookmark:[userInfo objectForKey:@"text"] :[userInfo objectForKey:@"book"] :[userInfo objectForKey:@"chapter"] :[userInfo objectForKey:@"verse"]];
        StatusViewController *detailViewController = [[StatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
        
        
        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        
        [detailViewController release];.this is my code in button click.statusviewcontroler is my posting page

Comment: postArray = [DbHandler getBookmarks]; this postarray is the mutablearray.it contains verses.i wna to  show it in my textview.but need to split it as string .i donno how to convert this as a string

Comment: Add a property `NSString *verseToBePosted` to StatusViewController, and set it between `alloc` and `pushViewController`?

Comment: For assembling strings from multiple parts look into `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`. It's hard to know what you need to do without knowing the structure of [DbHandler getBookmarks], what string you want, and where you want to put it.